# I would like to apply for an National Insurance number. I have a British passport, have never lived in the UK but am coming to live there this year

Tags: united-kingdom, insurance, pension

I am living in Zimbabwe but am a British Citizen and will be coming to the UK to live. I would like to get an National Insurance number and find out about back paying National Insurance.

Comment: Please can you clarify what do you mean about "back paying NI", as in what exactly you are trying to accomplish with that? I assumed it might has something to do with [Class 3 contributions](https://www.gov.uk/voluntary-national-insurance-contributions) but am not 100% sure, hence a comment.

Comment: I read on the Government Website that you have to have contributed for a minimum of 10years and you can back pay up to a maximum of 6 years. This is what I am trying to find out

Answer (score 3):

[This UK govt page](https://www.gov.uk/apply-national-insurance-number) lists the requirements to apply for a new National Insurance number. The first item is this:

> **Eligibility**
>
> You can apply for a National Insurance number if you live in the UK and have the right to work in the UK.

Thus, you'll have to wait to apply until after you've actually moved to the UK.